# Showing $ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\bf R}\frac{f(y)}{y-(x+i\varepsilon)}\ dy=f(x+i\varepsilon)$ in a discussion of Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In [this set of lecture notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf) by Terry Tao on the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform),
the following statement is made:

> Suppose $f\in C^1({\bf R})$ obeys a qualitative decay bound $f(x)=O_f(\langle x\rangle^{-1})$. Also suppose $f$ extends holomorphically to the upper half-plane and obeys the decay bound $f(z)=O_f(\langle z\rangle^{-1})$ in this region. Then Cauchy's theorem gives
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\bf R}
> \frac{f(y)}{y-(x+i\varepsilon)}=f(x)
> $$
> and
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\bf R}
> \frac{f(y)}{y-(x-i\varepsilon)}=0.
> $$

In the statement above, $\langle z\rangle:=\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$ denotes the Japanese bracket of $x$ (cf. [Tao's notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes2.pdf), corollary 6.7) and $O$ denotes the usual Big O notation (cf. [Tao's notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes1.pdf), section 3, Landau notation)

**Question**:

Would anyone elaborate how Cauchy's theorem (I think the "[Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)" would be more precise here) is applied here?

---

I attempted to use [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) with the semi-circle contour to show that
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\bf R}\frac{f(y)}{y-(x+i\varepsilon)}\ dy=f(x+i\varepsilon),\quad \varepsilon>0.
$$
But with the decay assumption of $f$, I don't see how to get
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\max_{\theta\in[0,\pi]}
\left|\frac{f(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}-(x+i\varepsilon)}\right|=0
$$

---

Here is a related excerpt from the notes (regarding the Plemelj formula and the discussion afterwards):

> [image]

[...]

> [image]

(The RHS of the first identity in the original notes should be $f(x)$ instead of $f(x+i\varepsilon)$.)

Comment: What does $f(z)=O_f(\langle z\rangle^{-1})$ mean? $|f(z)|\le C\cdot(\langle z\rangle^{-1})$ for some constant $C$ and sufficiently small $\langle z\rangle^{-1}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it the common big O notation as indicated in his [notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes0.pdf).

Comment: Ok... I've posted some sort of an answer, but it seems to me that it would hold with a weaker condition $f(z)=o(1)$ when $|z|\to\infty$, so I've got a bit of a doubt if I've understood the problem correctly. Have a look...

Comment: @user8734617 Thanks! The stronger assumption is for ensuring that $Hf$ is well-defined. I'm reading your answer. It seems that I made a rather dumb mistake when estimating the integral by putting the term $\langle z\rangle$ to the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a semi-circular path, consisting of $\ell_1=[-R,R]$ and $\ell_2=\{Re^{it}: 0\le t\le\pi\}$, we have:

$$\left|\int_{\ell_2}\frac{f(y)}{y-(x\pm i\varepsilon)}dy\right|\le C\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+R^2}}\times\frac{1}{|R-|x\pm\varepsilon||}\times \pi R$$

the factor $C\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+R^2}}$ coming from the estimate of $f$, the factor $\frac{1}{|R-|x\pm\varepsilon||}$ from the triangle inequality (estimate of $\frac{1}{y-(x\pm\varepsilon)}$), and the third factor is the length of the semicircle. The RHS $\to 0$ when $R\to\infty$.

On the other side,

$$\int_{\ell_1}\frac{f(y)}{y-(x\pm i\varepsilon)}dy=\int_{-R}^R \frac{f(y)}{y-(x\pm i\varepsilon)}dy$$

As the sum of those is a contour integral to which you can apply Cauchy's formula, the formulas from the red rectangle directly follow by letting $R\to\infty$.